# How do I map tags to tag synonyms?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I am building a system where users associate tags with posts, not unlike SO. I am having a spot of bother implementing [**tag synonyms**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work).

Here I have a table called **Tags**:

```
| TagName    |
|------------|
| Python     |
| JavaScript |
| Node       |
```

And I have another called **TagSynonyms**:

```
| SynonymId | SourceTagName | TargetTagName |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
| 1         | Py            | Python        |
| 2         | Python2       | Python        |
```

The server is implemented using Node and the user enters some tags as a comma-delimited string:

```
var input = 'Py,Flask'
var tags = request.tags.split(',');
```

In this case, the user has entered the tag **Py** which, according to the **TagSynonyms** table, should be mapped to the tag **Python**. The second tag, **Flask** has no synonym and should remain the same.

I managed to implement this functionality using imperative code:

```
tags.forEach(function (tag) {
  connection.query('SELECT TargetTagName FROM TagSynonyms WHERE SourceTagName = ?', tag, function(err, rows) {
    if (rows.length !== 0) {
      console.log(rows[0].TargetTagName);
    } else {
      console.log(tag);
    }
  });
});
```

Here, the user input

```
['Py','Flask']
```

results in the following output

```
Python
Flask
```

What I want to do is, defer this logic to the database engine, as  I think using a loop is a code smell. I also think the database engine will be more performant. What is an appropriate query to do this?

Comment: You can just `SELECT TargetTagName FROM TagSynonyms WHERE SourceTagName IN ?, tags`, to select all values from DB in one query

Comment: synonymid seems redundant

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I was thinking that too. I am not sure what else to use as the primary key at the moment.

Comment: @vanadium23 I think this will return a table with one row with the value **Python** whereas I want a result with two rows, **Python** *and* **Flask**. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Angularnoob I guess what is problem, rewrite query to `SELECT TargetTagName FROM TagSynonyms WHERE SourceTagName IN ('Py','Flask') OR TargetTagName IN ('Py','Flask')` will return Flask and Python

Comment: SourceTagName seems like a good candidate to me!

Comment: @vanadium23 I feel like that _should_ work but alas, I tried it and it still only returns one row with the value **Python**. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @Angularnoob answer is good and right ;-)

Comment: @Angularnoob Essentially, I think your existing approach is the correct one. The tags table is redundant here. Missing results will be more effectively processed in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry Would you care to elaborate? I am sorry, but I do not follow. The goal here is consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `UNION` and a join:

```
  select TagName
    from Tags
    where TagName in (?,?,?,...)
union
  select TagName
    from Tags
    join TagSynonyms
      on Tags.TagName = TagSynonyms.TargetTagName
    where TagSynonyms.SourceTagName in (?,?,?,...)
```

Note that `union` can be slow since it will try to remove duplicates. If that's the case for you, use `union all` and remove duplicates in the application code.

`(?,?,?,...)` stands for a list of input values; check your DB driver documentation for the exact syntax that you need to use to avoid SQL injection.

**Update:** Here is what the implementation will look like in Node:

```
var query = 
'SELECT TagName \
FROM Tags \
WHERE TagName IN (?) \
UNION \
SELECT TagName \
FROM Tags \
JOIN TagSynonyms \
  ON Tags.TagName = TagSynonyms.TargetTagName \
WHERE TagSynonyms.SourceTagName IN (?)'

connection.query(query, [tags, tags], function(err, rows) {
  tags = rows.map(function(row) { 
    return row.TagName
  });
});
```

Comment: I tested this in Workbench and I think it is ideal. I am going to try this in Node now, and I will get back to you. Thank you, Aaron!

Comment: @Strawberry: Without the first select, you wouldn't get `Python` for the input `Python`. The result of the query is a set of tags that the system knows about, either directly or via an alias. If you just wanted to convert aliases to names, you could just use the second query.

Comment: @AaronDigulla The first input was 'Py'. You still won't get 'Flask', so the application will have to do some post processing for missing results anyway. I'm not convinced that this offers any advantage over the existing solution.

Comment: @Strawberry You do get **Flask** provided **Flask** is already in the **Tags** table. I am very interested to hear your argument for my current solution!

Comment: @Angularnoob But it isn't: " The second tag, Flask has no synonym and should remain the same."

Comment: @Angularnoob Can users only submit tags (or synonyms of tags) that are already present in the tags table?

Comment: Hm. I did not think about that. You are _totally_ correct. Do you have any further thoughts, @AaronDigulla?

Comment: Stick with what you're doing, and handle missing or unsynonymised results in the application code.

Comment: @Angularnoob: Strawberry is right: You need to define a process which allows to create new tags. But for this process, you need a way to identify all tag names that you know and for that, the `union` is useful. Just modify the queries a bit to get all known names + aliases. You can them filter your input against it and do a second query to convert the known tags into "base tags".